# Expanded PrimeFaces's DataTable's rows misbehavior

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm not sure whether or not this is a datatable's row expansion misbehavior or am I doing something wrong. I'll be as simple as possible with the problem's description.

First, try making a DataTable like PrimeFaces's showcase for instance with a list of Car's in which you may "change" car's color. It's simple!

Then implement its `rowExpansion` in order to do the partial processing of a property `ActionListener` set via commandButton. Till there, everything is alright. So now try expand the last row and after that try expanding middle's one then click over `commandButton` of the first expanded row then you'll notice that the property `ActionListener` set will be pointed or related to the second expanded row. In my example, I just populate datatable's with 3 rows.

If you try to expand only one row you get the expected behavior.

It seems that the expansion process overwrite previous processed model or some sort of other misbehavior that's away from knowledge.

See the following snippets.

```
<p:dataTable id="carsTable" var="car" value="#{bean.carsSmall}">
  <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{bean.onRowToggle}" />
     <p:column style="width:2%">
        <p:rowToggler />
     </p:column>

    <p:column style="width:49%">
      <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="width:49%">
      <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:rowExpansion>
       <ui:repeat var="color" value="#{bean.availableColors}">
          <p:commandButton action="#{bean.chooseColor}" value="#{color.color}">
              <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.selectedColor}" value="#{color}" />
          </p:commandButton>
       </ui:repeat>

    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

Bean

```
@ManagedBean 
@SessionScoped 
public class Bean implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1708652163041196763L;

    private List<Car> carsSmall = new ArrayList<Car>();
    private final List<Color> availableColors = new ArrayList<Color>();
    private Color selectedColor;

    public Bean() {
        carsSmall.add(new Car("81025d15", "2011"));
        carsSmall.add(new Car("44194657", "2012"));
        carsSmall.add(new Car("482f2a60", "2013"));
    }

    public void clear(){
        this.availableColors.clear();
    }

    public void chooseColor(){
        System.out.println(this.selectedColor.getColor());
    }

    public void onRowToggle(ToggleEvent event) {
        // This is a dummy logic for this example...
        Car car = (Car) event.getData();
        this.availableColors.clear();

        if (car.getModel().equals("81025d15")) {
            this.availableColors.add(new Color("RED"));
            this.availableColors.add(new Color("GREEN"));
            this.availableColors.add(new Color("BLUE"));
        } else if (car.getModel().equals("44194657")) {
            this.availableColors.add(new Color("YELLOW"));
            this.availableColors.add(new Color("GRAY"));
            this.availableColors.add(new Color("BLACK"));
        } else if (car.getModel().equals("482f2a60")) {
            this.availableColors.add(new Color("ORANGE"));
            this.availableColors.add(new Color("BROWN"));
            this.availableColors.add(new Color("PINK"));
        }

    }
    // GETTERS and SETTERS...
}
```

For those who will point the cause of issue the fact I'm using `<ui:repeat>`, this misbehavior is also noticed with either `<h:dataTable>` or `<p:dataTable>`

This example does not function with bean set as neither as `RequestScoped` nor `ViewScoped`.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in [PrimeFaces forum: Expanded DataTable's rows misbehavior](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=33141&p=105224#p105224),

In short, your code is working as (you) designed (it). :)

I downloaded your code to my PC, changed your code, and i got the expected behavior working good.

Added List availableColors to 'Car'

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.rowexpansion;

import java.util.List;

public class Car implements java.io.Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 2296448576778208049L;

   private String model;
   private String year;
   private String color;
   private List<Color> availableColors;

   public Car() {
   }

   public Car(String model, String year) {
      super();
      this.model = model;
      this.year = year;
   }

   public String getModel() {
      return model;
   }

   public void setModel(String model) {
      this.model = model;
   }

   public String getYear() {
      return year;
   }

   public void setYear(String year) {
      this.year = year;
   }

   public String getColor() {
      return color;
   }

   public void setColor(String color) {
      this.color = color;
   }

    public List<Color> getAvailableColors() {
        return availableColors;
    }

    public void setAvailableColors(List<Color> availableColors) {
        this.availableColors = availableColors;
    }

}
```

Modified Bean: removed 'final' List availableColors and rowToggler event, and populated Car.availableColors() in bean's constructor

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.rowexpansion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Bean implements java.io.Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1708652163041196763L;

   private List<Car> carsSmall = new ArrayList<Car>();
   private Color selectedColor;

   public Bean() {
        List<Color> availableColors;
        carsSmall.add(new Car("81025d15", "2011"));
        availableColors = new ArrayList<Color>();
        availableColors.add(new Color("RED"));
        availableColors.add(new Color("GREEN"));
        availableColors.add(new Color("BLUE"));
        carsSmall.get(0).setAvailableColors(availableColors);

        carsSmall.add(new Car("44194657", "2012"));
        availableColors = new ArrayList<Color>();
        availableColors.add(new Color("YELLOW"));
        availableColors.add(new Color("GRAY"));
        availableColors.add(new Color("BLACK"));
        carsSmall.get(1).setAvailableColors(availableColors);

        carsSmall.add(new Car("482f2a60", "2013"));
        availableColors = new ArrayList<Color>();
        availableColors.add(new Color("ORANGE"));
        availableColors.add(new Color("BROWN"));
        availableColors.add(new Color("PINK"));
        carsSmall.get(2).setAvailableColors(availableColors);
   }

   public void chooseColor(){
      System.out.println(this.selectedColor.getColor());
   }

   public List<Car> getCarsSmall() {
      return carsSmall;
   }

   public void setCarsSmall(List<Car> carsSmall) {
      this.carsSmall = carsSmall;
   }

   public Color getSelectedColor() {
      return selectedColor;
   }

   public void setSelectedColor(Color selectedColor) {
      this.selectedColor = selectedColor;
   }

}
```

removed the rowToggle AJAX event from xhtml; don't need it, really.

```
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{bean.onRowToggle}" />
```

Last, I changed 'bean.availableColors' to 'car.availableColors'

```
<ui:repeat var="color" value="#{car.availableColors}">
    <p:commandButton action="#{bean.chooseColor}" value="#{color.color}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.selectedColor}" value="#{color}" />
     </p:commandButton>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Hey, I already noticed your answer on primefaces's forum. But still a question... Why does this doesn't work properlly with a `RequestedScope` bean?